# New google homepage ? good or bad ?

Tags: google

I just saw that google updated its homepage for logged users at least.
The top menu bar is redesigned.

What do you guys think about it ?

[image]

Comment: Closing because I don't see an actual question here.

Comment: I believe the question was whether the change of UI was a good design decision from an UX point of view (and of so, what are the benefits) or merely cosmetic eye candy (at least that's how I understood it).

Comment: @wildpeaks - questions looking for nothing but opinions don't really belong on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the developer's point of view, it is slightly frustrating because I have recently made a webapp for a customer which looks very similar, so everyone will believe it is copied from Google while it's not.

From the Google user's point of view, I like the change: it uses less screen space without sacrificing functionnalities, and follow the visual standards of mobile and web apps.

Comment: There's only one solution - sue google! ;-)

Comment: Sure and I'll buy Microsoft with the settlement money :-D

Comment: When you are done, let me know. I need a few Visual Studio bugs to be fixed...

Answer (score 2):

I think it's clean design when links aren't underlined. Blue text is enough to say - "this is a link". Just look at this page - works like a charm :)

I also think that this design follow the Google way of doing things, minimal to keep the workflow in focus and I am pretty sure that Apples glossy buttons and 3d effects are going to be outdated in a short future.

Windows Phone 7 has taken that path and I like it.
[image: Windows Phone 7 GUI]

Comment: The way the "Explorer", "Power", and "notes" text are being cropped out is bugging me so much!

Answer (score 2):

I think Google is a unique case!

- since most people use Google, they already know where to click and what they will get
- with this little mod shown on your pic is nice! it has a 'modern' feeling but still fits to Google's usual minimalistic design

Answer (score 2):

With the new UI, Google finally looks like it's "Web 2.0" site. The previous link were just to plain and boring. Love the blue line over the select text.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better than the previous revision, especially the drop down menu. When you click 'more' to open the drop down menu, it's more easy to click the links.

Answer (score 1):

I will add my opinion as well.

I like for the looks. The only things that i don't like is the dropdown for multiple sign in.
I have to click more before i get the whole list. I can't see a reason why they wouldnt put the whole list in the drodown and mark the current one.